# mysql drop table if exists inside procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure, sql-drop

I'm trying to apply a nested set model example with procedures. I've found many of them with this technique and in the process I've found a problem. Every time I call the procedure I get `unknown table XXX`. When I create the procedure I got no problem at all. The quick example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_getRoleTree` (IN root INT)
  READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE rows SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ROLE_TREE;
    CREATE TABLE ROLE_TREE (
        nodeID INT PRIMARY KEY
    ) ENGINE=HEAP;

    INSERT INTO ROLE_TREE VALUES (root);

    SELECT * FROM ROLE_TREE;
    DROP TABLE ROLE_TREE;
END;
```

So my question is, am I doing something wrong here (it's example code), can I disable the warning on the if exists if the code is fine? Is there a special looping inside the procedures that's causing these kind of warnings?

Comment: Why do you need this table? If you want to output a data-set from the procedure - just run SELECT query.

Comment: Not just a data set... a nested set, it's for hierarchical data parent-child-grandchild relationships. Basically you create a table hierarchy that can be fetched to evaluate relationship. The example above is a portion of the actual procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a work around: try to truncate table instead of re-creating.

Do not use `DROP TABLE`/`CREATE TABLE`. Create this table once (or when you need it) and use `TRUNCATE TABLE` command.

Comment: This seems a possible solution. Still, don't undestand why books like **Get It Done With MySQL 5&6** by _Peter Brawley and Arthur Fuller_ explain this kind of solutions without naming this kind or error. Is it a mysql bug? or configuration issue?

Comment: Looks like configuration issue.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL generates a warning when using `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl;` when the table does not exist.  This can be confusing and perhaps counter intuitive, but it is the expected behavior.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/drop-table.html

> Use IF EXISTS to prevent an error from occurring for tables that do not exist. A NOTE is generated for each nonexistent table when using IF EXISTS. See Section 13.7.5.41, [SHOW WARNINGS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-warnings.html).

IF EXISTS prevents MySQL from throwing an error, which is nice, but it causes a warning if the table does not exist.  There is not an option to suppress this warning.

Comment: Thanks, I've followed @Devart solution at the end (which seem logic to me as the procedure runs over a program) but your extra info always help